# Toggle css (display:none) not working on safari

Tags: html, css, toggle, expand

Im trying to make this work on safari, but I haven't been able to, no matter what. It works fine on chrome/ff.

Im trying to do an expand box on click, here my code, Thanks in advance for any help:

```
<input class="toggle-box" id="header1" type="checkbox" >
<label for="header1">Click here</label>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing.</span>
```

css:

```
<style>
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.toggle-box + label + span {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + span {
  display: inline;
}

.toggle-box + label:before {
  background-color: #4F5150;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
.rest{
    display: inline!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what are the `+` signs in your selectors for? ah ok looked em up...

Comment: @Homungus: It's the Adjacent sibling selector, see here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors.

Comment: This selector means that the style applies only to label directly following a span, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Safari. For some reason, it seems to have problems toggling the `display` property.
I switched to

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0
  height: 0
}
```

now it seems to work. I guess `visibility: hidden` could work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my toggle button

[touch](https://codepen.io/atropat/pen/BapQRWP?editors=1000)

```
      <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="toggle_background">
      <div class="circle-icon"></div>
      <div class="vertical_line"></div>

    </span>

  </label>
```

or search "autoprefixer" in google